# Native Module cannot be null - when integrating react-native project inside another react-native project

Tags: react-native

I have a react-native cross platform project based on Underdark library for exchanging data using Bluetooth and Wifi. this is working as react-native project. I am able to transfer data between iPhone and android.

Now i want to integrate this into another react native project as a package or use it in another project. But the private Underdark react native project is not a proper package in itself. It is just a working react native project.

I have integrated by using the following commands.

1. npm install —save
2. In Xcode I have imported the project and added the libraries/framework (underdark and protocol buffers ) into Build phases.
3. On the react side the entire project gets installed under node-modules.
4. Now i create a component and import the files in underdark library in node modules.
5. I run the react-native run-ios command to run it on my device.
6. It builds successfully but gives the following error.

**2017-06-29 12:31:27.406 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Native module cannot be null.**

**2017-06-29 12:31:27.523 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)**

My question is

1. Is it possible to use a react native project in another project as a third party library. even if it is not a package.
2. How to remove this error.

[image]